# Mount a partition when accessing a file in it or cd into it

Tags: linux, mount, udev, automounting

I'd like a partition on a hard-disk to be mounted
when I try to access it.

For example, if `/dev/sda2` has label `SDA2`, when I
`cd /media/root/SDA2`

`/dev/sda2` will be mounted on `/media/root/SDA2`.

I searched for an udev rule with no result.

Comment: Why not just mount it at boot time?

Comment: Look into autofs https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs, or automount with systemd.

Comment: @maulinglawns: thanks, I followed your "automount with systemd" and it seems to work. I tried `systemctl is-enabled ... .automount`, it says"disabled" but nevertheless it works